# How to install Java 21 on Termux?

Tags: java, android, termux, java-21, openjdk-21

So Java 21 is already out but not even Java 20 is accessible on Termux. Is there any alternative way to use Java 21 on Termux or any IDE supported Java 21 on Android Phone?

I tried to install it on termux using the `pkg install openjdk-21` but it didn't work
[Installing Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umof6.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0c5J.jpg)

Comment: Why do you want to install a JDK in Android?

Comment: Providing installer packages that work without problems can take some time. Just be patient and wait some days.

Comment: @aled because some personal reason like I can't use my laptop due to technical problem

Answer (score 0):

**To install Java 21 on Termux**:

1. Download the jdk21 tar file from the official website. (If you want it for Termux, you need to download the aarch64 version.)
2. Extract the file with the `tar -xvf` command.
3. Add the Java folder to the path.
4. Run the Java command.
   (If you encounter an execution error, try it with `grun java`.)

Comment: Did you already tried your method? Can you run java -version command in termux?